# Unable to send bitcoin from trust wallet getting Code 400

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, sending, trust-wallet

I tried to send bitcoin from my trust wallet to my Coinbase account and I received an error  -26: Txn-mempool-conflict  Code 400 I am a beginner so can someone help me with this

Answer (score 0):

I have read that "txn-mempool-conflict happens when inputs have already been spent and you try to spend again."

I would check the list of recent transactions made by the wallet.